# Resize CentOs partition from another partition that already exist

Tags: centos, disk-space-utilization

I have a server CentOs, I'm new to server's world, so I have one /dev/sda3 partition almost full of files, and another one /dev/sda5 bigger and empty, how can I resize the bigger empty one partition to use more space for the first full partition without delete anything? See the photo for actual partition

[Actual partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y90Lz.png)

Comment: Boot with an Ubuntu or Mint live disk and resize using gparted.  Backup and verify first of course...

Comment: There is no way to do this from ssh? I don't have here the server

Comment: Can't really do anything to/with partitions on a disk that is in use.  Some VPS providers provide a "rescue boot" that could let you do it, but if this is a box in a rack somewhere ... Alternatively (and it is somewhat hackish and I would document EVERYTHING quite clearly for the next person to touch the system) if there is sufficient free space in places you could copy/move directories around and use filesystem links to make it seem like they are all in the places they normally would be.  What to do this to depends on what the server is actually doing...

Comment: Sure you could do this online, but you would have to log in directly as root, rather than as a user using sudo.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have root access how I can do this resize? Can you explain better to a newbie?